# MDX Expression to restrict access to Measure Group

Tags: security, mdx, role, ssas-2008

Say I have a bunch of measures which I wanted certain people to be unable to see (or vice versa only allow them to see) what kind MDX expression would I add to the SSAS Role?

I can get the user identity through the USERNAME function.

Is it even possible?

I can easily construct Dimension based security expressions, but I can't see how the Measures dimension access can be similarly curtailed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the Cell Data tab in the role file.

When you enable the read permissions, the user will be dissallowed any access to cell data inside the cube.

In this place you must define the set of measures that the user will be able to see by providing the proper MDX epression.

The [scope](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms145515.aspx) declation will provide you with information to write MDX expressions for the definiton of the data sets. (**SCOPE is used for a totally different purpose and should not be used for permissions - only for reference for the needed MDX expressions**)

Comment: Thank you. Is this CELL security? I want to avoid this if possible.

Comment: This IS Cell security. This essentially means that you protect cells (measure-results) from unauthorised access. I personally don't know any other way to do it. Even if your Facts are also dimensions, measures and dimensions are a totally different object and are handled as such by SSAS.

Comment: Thanks you @Thanos. I'll investigate this. I've been shy of cell security after some bad performance experiences in the past. I will reinvestigate